# How long it takes for `Topic` to be approved, and who approve it on Stack Overflow Documentation Beta?

Tags: support, documentation

I suggested a topic in the Stack Overflow documentation beta, but it is still shows the status as 'Awaiting approval'.

I would like to know how long it takes for a topic to get approved?
And who approves it, are they the users like us or some one from the Stack Overflow team?

Comment: Ironically, there is no documentation for Documentation. Topics are approved by the community. There is no set period of time that it takes.

Comment: This begs the question... How deep is your documentation? **Not deep enough**

Comment: It is a number of hours equal to the number of licks it takes to get to the center of a tootsie pop.

Comment: @CodyGray *there is no documentation for Documentation*: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/documentation/topics?

Comment: It depends on the tag in which your topic is suggested. I've had topics, examples, etc. lay around for weeks before being approved in the [DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/dom/topics) tag. Mostly that's because people think there's no difference between DOM and JavaScript, and I tend to suggest large changes, because DOM needs it.

Comment: Wow, that is... incredible. Here's the product, now figure it out for yourself and use it to write your own documentation. No wonder that isn't working out so well. The documentation for Documentation is equally as bad as all the other documentation on Documentation. So much for setting the bar high. I guess that ship sailed when the private beta ended and there was nothing of value that had been created. Ship it anyway, it's *bound* to be useful for something, right?